# What's the difference between term_id and term_taxonomy_id

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

The title says it all. At the moment in my custom taxonomies I'm getting the terms using the term id and taxonomy name.

Thought this question would've been asked before but can't find it anywhere! So just thought I'd ask and see if anyone has any answers.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you take a look into the Wordpress documentation you will find [Wordpress Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Taxonomy)

- **term_id** is the ID of a term in the terms table
- **term_taxonomy_id** is a unique ID for the term + taxonomy pair.

Comment: so manipulating and grabbing terms based only on the term_id wouldn't cause duplicates then?

Comment: actually just answered that last question. Had a look at the wp_terms table and yep using the term_id only is safe. Thanks for your reply @Juan

Comment: Just a note that in WordPress 4.2 [all terms were split](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/02/16/taxonomy-term-splitting-in-4-2-a-developer-guide/), meaning that each `term_id` will now occur only once in the `term_taxonomy` table (before the column wasn't unique and terms could be shared across taxonomies). This may continue to evolve in future, based on the [taxonomy roadmap](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2013/07/28/potential-roadmap-for-taxonomy-meta-and-post-relationships/). One part of that is to [combine the term and term taxonomy tables](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30262).

Comment: @J.D. so upsetting that after 8 years those tables are not yet combined

Answer (score 17):

**The Codex says:**

- term_id is the ID of a term in the terms table
- term_taxonomy_id is a unique ID for the term+taxonomy pair

**What does this mean?**

A term is a word. It can belong to a taxonomy, such as tags, categories, or a custom taxonomy. The thing is: there can be several taxonomies containing the same term.

Let’s say you have a term called “fattening“. This word has an id number. This is the term_id. It doesn’t depend on how this word is used, i.e. in which taxonomies the term appears.

Now the word “fattening” as a post tag also has a number. This is the term_taxonomy_id. It corresponds to “the post tag ‘fattening’“.

Maybe you also have a category called “fattening”. While the term_id is the same, the term_taxonomy_id for “the category ‘fattening’” is different.

Answer (score 11):

As this is a part of a bigger understanding of the design I will describe it as whole... :)

In WP 4.5.3 there are still all these tables (I will talk about them *without* prefix):

- posts
- term_relationships
- term_taxonomy
- terms

The path to get post terms' readable names goes through them all.

**posts**

the main identificator here is `ID` - an id of a post (of any type)

**term_relationships**

stores pairs of:

`object_id` - *can* be `posts.ID` (but does *not* have to be)

**`term_taxonomy_id`** - this is **NOT** id of a term (category) but an **id of *RELATIONSHIP*** between a term(category) and taxonomy("category type")

**term_taxonomy**

the main identificator here is **`term_taxonomy_id`** desribed above ^^

another important columns:

**`term_id`** - **an id of a term** (category)

`taxonomy` - stores the term's taxonomy("category type")

This one might seem funny, but the initial intend was to add the ability for terms to have more taxonomies (which in *some* cases can make sense).

**terms**

the main identificator here is the **`term_id`** - an id of an category

another important columns here are:

`name` - readable category name e.g. "Music Genres"

`slug` - the slug of a term usable e.g. in URL

So the *brutal* demonstrating SQL to

*get all published posts and all their categories with categories' names*

could look like this (add prefixes to tables when testing on your own WP DB):

```
SELECT * FROM
posts #gets posts
LEFT JOIN
term_relationships #gets posts relationships to term_taxonomies
ON(posts.ID=term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN
term_taxonomy #gets term_ids 
ON(term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id=term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN
terms #finally, gets terms' names
ON(term_taxonomy.term_id=terms.term_id)
WHERE (
    (posts.post_status='publish') 
    #optionally you can filter by a certain post_type:
    #AND
    #(posts.post_type='some_post_type')
)
ORDER BY posts.ID ASC
```

Comment: Hands down the clearest explanation on this thread... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> A term is not a category or tag on its own. It must be given context via the term_taxonomy table.
>
> The term_taxonomy table places a term within a taxonomy. This is what
>   makes a term a **category**, a **tag** or part of a **custom taxonomy** (or in a
>   combination of taxonomies).
>
> `term_id` is the ID of a term in the terms table.
>
> `term_taxonomy_id` is a unique ID for the term+taxonomy pair.

The `term_id` is always unique just like the `term_taxonomy_id`.
Both have an `Auto Increment` in the table structure.

The table `wp_term_taxonomy` makes sure for example that a category is created, so wordpress can interfere with it e.g Woocommerce uses: `product_tag`, `product_type`, `product_cat`, all of them are the so called custom taxonomies.
This table also binds the parent/children structure. With it's column `parent`.

> The final table, term_relationships, relates objects such as posts or links to a term_taxonomy_id from the term_taxonomy table.

If we pick Woocommerce again as an example, this table links post type `products` to their taxonomy `product_cat`, which contains a namy e.g Computers which is of course retrieved from the table `wp_terms`. This table contains the `term_id`, `name`, `slug` and `term_group`. (term_group I personally have never used)

Hopefully the above makes things a bit more clear about the differences and how Wordpress uses these tables.

Answer (score 0):

The Article "[Understanding and Working with Taxonomies and Terms in WordPress](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-and-working-with-taxonomies-and-terms-in-wordpress--cms-21051)" explains the reason for using two separate tables - `wp_term` and `wp_term_taxonomy`:

> In many WordPress installations, there will be one record in the `wp_term_taxonomy` table for each term in the `wp_terms` table, but in some cases you will have more than one record for each term. This happens when you create two terms with the same name and slug in different taxonomies, and means that you could create a query to output posts with that term in multiple taxonomies.
>
> This means that the relationship between these two tables is one-to-many: one record in the `wp_terms table` can be linked to multiple records in the `wp_term_taxonomy` table, but each record in `wp_term_taxonomy` is only linked to one record in `wp_terms`.