# wp_update_nav_menu_item not saving in multisite API

Tags: menus, multisite, settings-api

I'm creating a script that automates build a wordpress site from another CMS.
I've been able to change every setting: themes, options, subdomain, site title, etc.

But what is eluding me is being able to create custom menus.
The code below SHOULD be able to do it for me. However it is not, and I am completely stumped on what to do.

This code is not being executed in the admin panel (Its not a plugin). Its actually sitting on top of wordpress and includes wp-load and wp-admin functions pages.

```
$mymenu = wp_get_nav_menu_object("Main Navigation Menu");
$menuID = (int) $mymenu->term_id;
$itemData = array(
    'menu-item-db-id' => 0,
    'menu-item-object-id' => $pageId,
    'menu-item-object' => 'page',
    'menu-item-type'  => 'post_type',
    'menu-item-parent-id' => 0,
    'menu-item-position' => $itemOrder,
    'menu-item-title' => $pageData['title'],
    'menu-item-url' => get_permalink($pageId),
    'menu-item-description' => $pageData['post_content'],
    'menu-item-attr-title' => $pageData['post_excerpt'],
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish',<br />
    'menu-item-target' => ''<br />
);
$thisMenuItem = wp_update_nav_menu_item($menuID, 0, $itemData);
```

$itemData is the result of data coming in from another CMS plus the result of saving it off a post in wordpress to produce the menu item that I want in my menu.
Any help on getting the wp_update_nav_menu_item to save would be very helpful.
Again this is creating a custom menu without the use of the admin panel.`

Comment: Small update to this. I know that the items are getting into the database and saving as post_type nav_menu_item. However they are not being connecting to their parent.

Comment: Are you using [WordPress Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)? Just to understand why you titled and tagged like that and are not mentioning it in the content...

Comment: Yes I am. Sorry I forgot to mention it, but I finally figured out my issues late last night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$wpdb->insert( 
    $wpdb->term_relationships, 
    array(
        "object_id" => $thisMenuItem, 
        "term_taxonomy_id" => $menuID
    ), 
    array( "%d", "%d" ) 
);
```

This was missing from the Question code.
It allows the menu items to bind to the navigation menu itself.

Answer (score 1):

While Paul's answer was really helpful and definitely put me in the right direction, his code didn't quite work for my issue.

Basically, the function `wp_get_nav_menu_object()` returns the `$menu` object which has (among others) `term_id` and `term_taxonomy_id` properties.

On my clients WP instance `term_id` and `term_taxonomy_id` weren't the same.

What Paul does is insert the `term_id` property in the relationship table and link it to `term_taxonomy_id` column, but in my case I had to insert the `term_taxonomy_id` property from the `$menu` object (and looking at the naming - I believe this is proper).

Here's the [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37721/whats-the-difference-between-term-id-and-term-taxonomy-id) if you want to check up on the difference between `term_id` and `term_taxonomy_id`.

So in the end, my code ended up looking like this:

```
$wpdb->insert(
    $wpdb->term_relationships, 
    array(
        "object_id"        => $menu_item_id, 
        "term_taxonomy_id" => $menu->term_taxonomy_id
    ), 
    array(
        "%d", 
        "%d"
    )
);
```