# Wordpress ERD mistake?

Tags: database

I just had a look at the ERD of the Wordpress CMS system and I think I found a mistake... Check the relation between the wp_term_taxonomy and the wp_terms table: https://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png

If I'm correct ONE wp_term_taxonomy (like "brands") can have more wp_terms (like "puma", "nike" etc.) and not otherwise? Cause it says now that one term can have more taxonomies, am I right?

Comment: Erik, can you please move the solution to an Answer and mark it as the correct one? So this Question doesn't remain "unanswered", thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason:

term_id is the ID of a term in the terms table.

term_taxonomy_id is a unique ID for the term + taxonomy pair.

see: [What's the difference between term_id and term_taxonomy_id](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37721/whats-the-difference-between-term-id-and-term-taxonomy-id)

Still, I think it's a bit strange to do it this way. Also because I think it doesn´t make sence to not put the taxonomy names in a separate table.